# I want a default VPC to appear as one IP address, but will adding this make my AWS/EC2 more complex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My application runs behind an ELB on EC2 instances. Sometimes it sends out requests to remote services. I'd like requests to those remote services to appear to all come from a single IP address. It occurs to me that if all my machines were in an Amazon VPC, that would be the case.

Following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html), I've noticed that my AWS account does not have a default VPC. I have an old account that I inherited, so it may have been deleted or may never have existed.

I can apparently contact AWS support and have them set one up, but I'm worried: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961353/should-i-use-amazons-aws-virtual-private-cloud-vpc/11970160#11970160) and [this](http://blog.engineering.kiip.me/post/12288961849/ec2-to-vpc-transition-worth-doing) make it sound like once I start using VPC, I have to deal with subnets, routing tables, internet gateways, NAT devices, network ACLs, ... my oh my.

Will Amazon VPC do what I want? Will it add complexity?

Comment: FYI you can now programmatically create a new default VPC (except in regions that support EC2-Classic when your account also supports EC2 Classic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "default" VPC is one that is used as the "default". That is, when you do something, it will be the default selected VPC. There is nothing to worry about here. Anything you create can be as good as or better than the "default". I deleted the default VPC set up a new VPC last week and it was very easy.

Here are the steps I followed in order:

1. Create a new VPC
2. Create a Subnet in the desired Availability Zone, 10.0.0.0/24
3. [Important] Associate the Subnet with a Route (not the main one)
4. Create a Security Group for the VPC
5. Launch an Instance of Amazon Linux into the VPC
6. Create and assign an Elastic IP

Edit: You'll probably also want to create an ELB for the VPC and assign the Elastic IP to that.

Comment: @Adam Monsen - Did this help you? Do you have any additional questions or need more information?